# IE7 CSS background-size:100% fallback

Tags: internet-explorer, css

Anyone have a fallback for CSS background-size:100% for IE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check with the link:

http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

It might be works for you.

Comment: Hi thanks for this, i've tried one of the tricks in that link which is : progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='.myBackground.jpg', sizingMethod='scale');

Comment: This works, and scales the background image to 100%, but it position is 50% off?

Comment: please try to set position. It will work.

Comment: set background position? background-position will work in IE7?

Answer (score 0):

Try these css options

```
 min-height: 100%;
 min-width: 1024px;
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
```

Comment: sorry this wont work as my div has to be a fixed height and width

Answer (score 0):

i am not exactly sure this work but you can try this js here is the link of js https://github.com/louisremi/jquery.backgroundSize.js

```
$("h2#news").css({backgroundSize: "cover"});
```

let me know if you have any issue in this or you can also try filter for ie

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(
src='images/logo.gif',
sizingMethod='scale');
```

Comment: Hi @Sarfaraz ive tried backgroundSize.js, but its not working and i think cover stretches image up, i need to scale down

Comment: have you tried filter script ???

Comment: yes the filter script works well for IE8, but in IE7 the background resizes down, but looks like the background x position shifts 50%?