# html input fields stop working when I try to use css filters in ie8 to stretch background

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-8

I needed to stretch a background image on my site so that it always fills the available window area no matter what the resolution. My initial choice was of course `background-size:cover;`, but as usual, IE doesn't seem to like valid css, so I had to use:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(
 src='images/bg.jpg',
 sizingMethod='scale');

 -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(
 src='images/bg.jpg',
 sizingMethod='scale')";
```

However, though now the background stretches properly, for some reason all input fields have stopped working, as if they are behind an invisible element and are not clickable or selectable in any way. Any ideas what to do?

I know I can probably use javascript to manually set the image dimensions on window resize, but it isn't as smooth as the css alternative especially when I have to calculate the image dimentsions and make sure that the scaling occurs proportionately.

Comment: Hmm. Your claim of "but as usual, IE doesn't seem to like valid css" is flawed in that `background-size` is a CSS3 property which didn't exist when IE8 was released back at the start of 2009.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this:
http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

There's a CSS-only technique provided wich should work for older browsers as well and may solve your problem. I took this from a similar closed topic, see: 
[IE7 CSS background-size:100% fallback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13659274/ie7-css-background-size100-fallback)